# Error CS0012: The type 'Task' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: xamarin

I got this error when trying to build using a pre-built template from Xamarin:

> Error CS0012: The type 'Task' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced
>
> You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Where can I find the file to add these references?

Answer (score 0):

add reference from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5...\System.Threading.Tasks.dll